# Google Sheets: Displaying month with leading zero in array formula

Tags: google-sheets

My current array formula is `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A8:A <> ""; YEAR(A8:A) & "/" & MONTH(A8:A); ""))`

which turns "16 january 2016" etc. into "2016/1"

However when I later pull them elsewhere they're in the wrong order:
2017/1
2017/11
2017/2

This is because months are showing as '1' instead of '01'. How can this be remedied?

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uT1lfXcLRh182aTpVCDdozIyIx4RMjy9RFKyk0Ajfwc/edit#gid=0)

Comment: We prefer questions to be self-contained. While adding a link to a sample sheet is good for supplemental information, on its own it is problematic. What happens when you stop sharing that sheet? This question becomes absolutely worthless. Can you [edit] your question to include enough information so someone has an opportunity to answer without following the link?

Answer (score 3):

Use [TEXT function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) to format the month column. Your array formula would change to:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A8:A <> ""; YEAR(A8:A) & "/" & TEXT(MONTH(A8:A);"00"); ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

while Nick's answer may be sufficient:

**`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A8:A<>"";YEAR(A8:A)&"/"&TEXT(MONTH(A8:A);"00");""))`**

[image: 1]]

(see the result: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaWsZ1Xt1GLunL40Y96WEtfoE7Q2x6_yBnjZhtXfS2g/edit#gid=1699887427)**)

---

#### **there are also other approaches which can lead to similarly different results:**

---

## METHOD 1:

```
=SORT(QUERY(A8:C;

           "select C, sum(B) where C != '' group by C order by C asc label sum(B)''");

            DATE(YEAR (INDEX(QUERY(A8:C;

           "select C, sum(B) where C != '' group by C order by C asc label sum(B)''");;1));

                 MONTH(INDEX(QUERY(A8:C;

           "select C, sum(B) where C != '' group by C order by C asc label sum(B)''");;1));

                 DAY(1));1)
```

this is a 1-line formula in which format of date stays as `2016/1` and soring is done first by year and then by month

[image: 3]]

(see the result: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaWsZ1Xt1GLunL40Y96WEtfoE7Q2x6_yBnjZhtXfS2g/edit#gid=340507963)**)

---

## METHOD 2:

the result is the same as in the method 1, however with the usage of side calculations in hidden columns using a formula:

```
=QUERY(A8:C;"select C, sum(B) where C != '' group by C order by C asc label sum(B)''"; 0)
```

and then getting the desired data with a formula:

```
=SORT(H8:I;DATE(YEAR(H8:H);MONTH(H8:H);DAY(1));1)
```

[image: 5]]

(see the result: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaWsZ1Xt1GLunL40Y96WEtfoE7Q2x6_yBnjZhtXfS2g/edit#gid=1763422725)**)

---

## METHOD 3:

```
=SORT(QUERY(A8:C;

         "select C, sum(B) where C != '' group by C order by C asc label sum(B)''");

      MONTH(INDEX(QUERY(A8:C;

         "select C, sum(B) where C != '' group by C order by C asc label sum(B)''");;1));1)
```

this is a 1-line formula in which format of date also stays as `2016/1` and soring is done first by month and then by year (eg. it will create clusters based on months) **note the change in B5**

[image: 7]]

(see the result: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaWsZ1Xt1GLunL40Y96WEtfoE7Q2x6_yBnjZhtXfS2g/edit#gid=65513290)**)

---

## METHOD 4:

the result is the same as in the method 3, however with the usage of side calculations in hidden columns using a formula:

```
=QUERY(A8:C;"select C, sum(B) where C != '' group by C order by C asc label sum(B)''"; 0)
```

and then getting the desired data with a formula (**note the change in B5**):

```
=SORT(H8:I;MONTH(H8:H);1)
```

[image: 9]

(see the result: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaWsZ1Xt1GLunL40Y96WEtfoE7Q2x6_yBnjZhtXfS2g/edit#gid=359493710)**)

---

---

to fix **B5** you can change formula to: **`=AVERAGE(FILTER(F8:F;LEFT(E8:E;4)="2017"))`**

(see the fix: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CaWsZ1Xt1GLunL40Y96WEtfoE7Q2x6_yBnjZhtXfS2g/edit#gid=1219682538)**)

Comment: You call Method 1 a "1-line formula", but display it here as a **13-line** formula. Even in the screenshot, it's still taking up **4** lines. So what exactly do you mean by "1-line" in Method 1? Or was it a typo?

Comment: @TylerH lol, no typo there. "1-line formula" means that there is a single formula in a single cell that will do all the workload so there is no need for any helper columns. formula on screenshot has 4 lines because it was made that way on purpose to be more visually appealing, tho there is no need for that and it can be all put into a single line or every character of that formula can be on a separate line. "new lines" are introduced with CTRL+ENTER while typing the formula into fx bar and fx bar can be expanded with CTRL+ARROW_DOWN. this way you can create a nice overview for long formulae

Comment: I see, so in that case "1-line" is not really an accurate description; "a single formula" would be more apt.